# How can I sort a 2d array and keep track of the array indexes?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array which has 500 rows and 250 columns.

```
{ 0,  1,  2,  3, ... 250
  1,  1,  1,  1,
  2,  2,  2,  2,
  ...
  500
}
```

I would like to sort the values by column and be able to keep track of the original index with respect to the row position they were at.

How can I do this? previously when I had only one column I used the Comparator function, however now it doesn't seem like a feasible option.

Many thanks, I will make sure to choose a best answer.

Comment: use merge sort. divide 2d array until is become 2*2.

Comment: How did you use a `Comparator` to keep track of the original index?

Comment: Hi Vahid, could you please explain further. @Andrew, I had index values inputted into a second column which kept track of my first column

Comment: @AnthonyJ you could continue that strategy by making it a three dimensional array, and store original index in the third dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to use a datastructure to store both the original index and value:

```
class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{
    public int index;  //proper OOP would require using encapsulation, but for 
    public int value;  //demonstration I'll just use direct variable access

    public int compareTo(Entry e){
        return Integer.compare(value, e.value);
    }
}
```